# mapping excel columns to table column in database with python

Tags: python, excel, postgresql

**json file**

```
"mappingdef": [
                {
                    "src": "A",
                    "dest": "id"
                },
                {
                    "src": "B",
                    "dest": "expense_type"
                },
                {
                    "src": "C",
                    "dest": "balance"
                },
                {
                    "src": "D",
                    "dest": "debit"
                },
                {
                    "src": "E",
                    "dest": "credit"
                },
                {
                    "src": "F",
                    "dest": "total_balance"
                }
            ]
```

**my python script:**

#changing excel column names

```
df.columns = ["A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F"]
```

#fetching data from dataframe

```
for row in range(df.shape[0]):
    col_A = str(df.at[row, "A"]),
    col_B = str(df.at[row, "B"]),
    col_C = float(df.at[row, "C"]),
    col_D = float(df.at[row, "D"]),
    col_E = float(df.at[row, "E"]),
    col_F = float(df.at[row, "F"])
```

#query to insert data in database

```
query2 = """
    INSERT INTO ocean_street_apartments(
    id,
    expense_type,
    balance,
    debit,
    credit,
    total_balance)
    values (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s)
    """
```

i have this table definition info in json which tells src as excel column, and dest as database table column name. i want to read an excel file through pandas and want to map excel column (src) to database table column (dest). i am working in python

Comment: What did you try ?

Comment: i am fetching excel data from pandas column wise and storing them in some variables but didnt getting any idea how to map them to table column so that fetch data automatically will be saved to table columns we want for example i want column A and B data to be stored in one columns of table...

Comment: What I meant is : could you provide us with a reproducible example ? Give us a few lines of code, with example data (one or two records of your excel file, it could be dummy data), the desired output and the output you currently have ; that way we can better understand if you already managed to extract data, what format it has, and so on ... then we can go from there to find a solution.

Comment: For now, if your data is in a pandas dataframe, I would recommend you just rename the columns from the excel naming scheme to your new naming scheme using [Dataframe.rename](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.rename.html), then maybe use [Dataframe.to_sql()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_sql.html) to export it as a sql table.

Comment: What i have is one excel file which i m reading by pandas i just want a automate code in python to save A column of excel to 1st column of database table B column to 2nd column of table,   i have only a json file which is telling which excel column is going to save in this column of database table json file i have wrote above... I hope u are understanding my feelings...

Comment: However, you do not explain what the exact issue is. It seems as if you are askinf multiple things at the same time. If it's not opening the excel file with pandas, is it opening the json file ? Is it renaming the columns ? Is it exporting to sql statements ? Connecting to a database ? Is there an issue with your current code ? Did you look for a solution to any of these problems ? If we could see your current code (you can simplify it), it would be much easier to understand the exact issue, then to give a clear answer, for me and the other users that might stumble on your question.

Comment: Your answers make me think you want us to give out a complete script without you having to work on it. Sorry if I'm wrong, but this is not this kind of forum.

Comment: please help me now i have updated my script and sorry i am a newbie...

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that its JSON file so its an API get response.

Things i am assuming you know how to do:
1)fetch get response and what is returned is an array of object descriptions for every file.
2)create script to download this and move it to a DF.

Now you have a a list of direct links to our csv files! We can read these urls directly using **pandas.read_csv(url)**.

If data is problematic **transform** them.

It's time to Directly Load DF into a SQL DB using `pandas.DataFrame.to_sql`

Code below describes how to connect to a SQLite db.

```
def upload_to_sql(filenames, db_name, debug=False):
    """ Given a list of paths, upload to a database
    """
    conn = sqlite3.connect(f"{db_name}.db")
    
    if debug:
        print("Uploading into database")
    for i, file_path in tqdm(list(enumerate(filenames))):
        
        dat = pd.read_csv(file_path)

        # rename labels
        filename = os.path.basename(file_path).split('.')[0]
        dat = factor_dataframe(dat, filename)

        # write records to sql database
        if i == 0: # if first entry, and table name already exist, replace
            dat.to_sql(db_name, con=conn, index = False, if_exists='replace')
        else: # otherwise append to current table given db_name
            dat.to_sql(db_name, con=conn, index = False, if_exists='append')


# upload into sql database
upload_to_sql(download_urls, 'example', debug=True)
```

Comment: i dont want to save data with .tosql method, i want to save data in chunks column wise

Answer (score 0):

```
import psycopg2
import ijson

conn = psycopg2.connect(
    host="localhost",
    database="sea",
    user="postgres",
    password="hemant888")

cursor = conn.cursor()
chunk_size = 10
skiprows = 5
file_name = "Ocean Street Apartments Trial Balance 03-22.xlsx"

cursor.execute("""
        SELECT COUNT(*)
        FROM information_schema.tables
        WHERE table_name = 'ocean_street_apartments'
        """)

if cursor.fetchone()[0] != 1:
    columns = list()
    datatype = list()
    row = list()
    with open("tabledef.json", "r") as f:
        for record in ijson.items(f, "item"):
            for i in record["def"]["tabledef"]["columns"]:
                col = i["name"]
                columns.append(col)

                dt = i["datatype"]
                datatype.append(dt)

    for i in range(len(columns)):
        row.append("{col} {dt}".format(col=columns[i], dt=datatype[i]))

    query1 = "create table ocean_street_apartments(" + \
        ",".join(map(str, row)) + ")"

    cursor.execute(query1)
    conn.commit()

while True:
    df_chunk = pd.read_excel(file_name, skiprows=skiprows,
                             nrows=chunk_size)
    skiprows += chunk_size

# When there is no data, we know we can break out of the loop.
    if not df_chunk.shape[0]:
        break

    else:
        columns = list()
        columns_table = list()
        with open("tabledef.json", "r") as f:
            for record in ijson.items(f, "item"):
                for i in record["def"]["tabledef"]["mappingdef"]:
                    col = i["src"]
                    columns.append(col)

                    col_table = i["dest"]
                    columns_table.append(col_table)

        query2 = "INSERT INTO ocean_street_apartments(" + ",".join(
            map(str, columns_table)) + ")values (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s)"

        df_chunk.columns = columns
        values_list = list()
        for row in range(df_chunk.shape[0]):
            for col in df_chunk.columns:
                val = str(df_chunk.at[row, col])
                values_list.append(val)
            values = tuple(values_list)
            cursor.execute(query2, values)
            values_list = list(values)
            values_list.clear()
            values = tuple(values_list)
conn.commit()
conn.close()
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).